# Distribute a PhoneGap compiled IOS app without the Apple's app store

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

i want to know if its possible to distribute a phonegap app, without the app store.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Using phonegap build is this possible?

I saw this docs by apple, using enterprise solution, but i cant see how i can use it with phonegap.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

Comment: No, that's not possible !

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise account works irrespective of app is built in Hybrid or native.

Yes using PhonoGap build its possible to archive, However even using terminal on mac you can generate the project and archive in regular method.

Comment: How can i archive in the phonegap build cloud?

Comment: As of now i do not have credentials for phoneGap build. check this for clarity, (https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/installing-iphone-apps-without-a-mac-using-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build-3/)